# Problem Rigging "Set Parent to Automatic Weight"

Tags: rigging

Fellow Blenderers.
I am nothing but a humble student that's currently learning how to rig. I followed this tutorial

[image: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q9f-WVs3ghI]
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q9f-WVs3ghI

but it seems i have 2 problems that i cannot shackle no matter what.

1. My first problem is my leg bones gets wonky like a mad goblin everytime i raise it.

[image: The leg is supposed to rise to the front, but instead it rise to the left side.]

The leg is supposed to rise to the front, but instead it rise to the left side.

2. My second problem is everytime i set my mesh's parent to my bones...

[image]
[image]
[image: Ok, now this mad goblin looks like doing a Fortnite dance]

That happens everytime i set the parent to 'Automatic Weight'.

I have no idea what happen. I don't understand 3d at all.
Help me.

[image: enter image descripsione hwere]

By the way, here's the file if you want to see my misery.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Sr7SFxaqSTxwO1fUHxknl3S22rNIGY7v/view?usp=sharing

Comment: it could have something to do with the IK pole angle, but maybe share your file

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Sr7SFxaqSTxwO1fUHxknl3S22rNIGY7v/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Here, feel free to use it :)

Comment: you should apply the mirror of your object, but it won't fix everything on your armature, I'm not familiar with this bones setup, maybe I'll understand it...